# is it possible and reliable to access sqldatabase using javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net

I want to get the list of my database's elements.
but i wonder, is it possible and reliable to access sqldatabase using javascript?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but define _"reliable"_ please. And please avoid asking question their answer are YES\NO.

Comment: oh thanks, but my real question is 'how to succeed it?' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Ajax call to access the Server, to in turn retrieve the data.

Here is a sample code in jquery:

```
var requrl = "/test/test.php"; // or any server side page returning part html i.e. anything between body tags.

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'html', //change format if appropriate
        cache: false,
        url: requrl,
        success: function (data) {                    
                $('#idofdiv').html(data); //html Data returned by the server page will be populated in this div.
        },
        error: function (failure) {
                //alert(failure.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The best to do is to use ajax for that.

You can't access directly your database from your client. But your client can use ajax to contact a server that will access to your database and then return a result to the client.

That's the common way to do.

But if you want to use javascript on server directly, please provide more information.

Comment: so thanks @Jerome C. do you have any sample about it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use AJAX to access your database from JavaScript.  Since you have to give your username and password to access your database, it is better to do so behind the scenes using PHP or a server side language.

If you access it from JavaScript, then everyone will be able to see your password.

Comment: so thanks @Susanoh13. Do you have any suggested website using ajax for this work?

Comment: @MehmetInce No problem. I would recommend browsing [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) for a basic intro.